# fill ng-select items from an key value enum

Tags: angular, enums, typescript2.0, angular-ngselect

I have a problem with angular 10 and typescript, I have an enum looking like this :

```
export enum myEnum {

'type1' =  0, 
'type2' =  1, 
'type3' =  2, 
'type4' =  3 
}
```

and I would like to loop on my enum entries to fill an array of Types object
(the structure of Type is :

```
export class Type {
    id :number
    typeName : string
}
```

after that I'd like to put my array of Type in the items property of a  combobox.

How can I could do that simply ?

precision : I need a key/value object in my combobox for get the id value when I select on element and send it to backend.

edit :
I init the array like this :

```
types : Type[] = []

the array should be like this :
this.types = [{0,'type1'},{1, 'type2'}, {2, 'type3'}, {3, 'type4'}]
```

I need this array to be in the ng-select [items]

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Could you also paste in the exact output of the array you are expecting?

Comment: ok I edit the question !

Comment: `[{0,'type1'},{1, 'type2'}, {2, 'type3'}, {3, 'type4'}]` is not a valid json.

Comment: yes sorry i'ts a look like I do't need a json, just get the id I select and send it. the question is just how to fill my ng-select items with my enum.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can:

```
let i = 0;
while (myEnum[i]) {
  this.types.push({ id: i, type: myEnum[i++] });
}
```